# How do I set up a Google App Engine Project that uses Groovy in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, groovy

How do I make a Groovy Google App Engine project in Eclipse?  I have both the Groovy and the App Engine plugins installed.

I'm already able to successfully make an App Engine or a Groovy project separately, but how do I make a project that is both?

I tried just making an App Engine project and then adding a Groovy class to it, but I get this error when I click Finish on the "Create a new Groovy class" dialogue:

`Creation of element failed. Reason: groovytest does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it recently according to this sequence:

1. Download [Eclipse 3.5](http://eclipse.org/)
2. Download [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)
3. Install [Groovy plugin for IDE](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin)
4. Install [GAE plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/)
5. In Eclipse choose *New -> Web Application* Project (uncheck "Use Google Web Toolkit" if you are not going to use it)
6. Right click on the new project *Configure -> Convert to Groovy Project*
7. Download [Groovy GAE project template](http://zhaber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Groovy.tar.gz), unzip it
8. Right click on the project *Import... -> General -> File System*, browse to template project folder, check "Overwrite existing resources without warning"
9. Open *war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml* and change an application name to yours
10. Copy *groovy-all.jar* from Groovy Libraries to *war/WEB-INF/lib*
11. Right click on the build.groovy, *Run As -> Web Application*
12. Go to [http://localhost:8888](http://localhost:8888/)
13. To deploy choose *Google -> Deploy to App Engine* from a project context menu

FYI: GAE project template contains the hello.groovy file which is a kind of [Groovlet](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlets).

Answer (score 0):

Put the groovy-all-1.7.X.jar in the war/WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work:

I created a Google App Engine project in Eclipse, then I right clicked on it in package explorer, and went to `configure->Convert to Groovy Project`.